# Yocto extensible SDK devtool getting error while deploying a plain makefile hello world project

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, embedded-linux, yocto

I have created a custom yocto linux image for a raspberry pi and also an esdk.

I am trying to deploying a plain makefile helloworld project to a raspberry pi 3. I have tested the source code by building natively and running.

Then I set up a cross compiling environment and use devtool to add the source code. After that I try to build and deploy my recipe.

`devtool build` command is running succesfully without any error.

When i try `devtool deploy-target ...` I get the following error:

`ERROR: No files to deploy - have you built the hello recipe? If so, the install step has not installed any files.`

1. C++ source file (helloworld.cpp):

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <gnu/stubs.h>

   int main(void) {
       puts("Hello World!!!");
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```
2. Makefile

   ```
   PROJECT_NAME        := XYZ

   OUTPUT_DIR      := build

   CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

   SRCS = helloworld.cpp

   OBJS =$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

   LIBS =

   TARGET =    helloworld

   PREFIX = /usr/bin

   $(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

   .cpp.o:
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

   all:    $(TARGET)
       @echo Compiling project

   clean:
       rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)

   build_directory: $(OUT_DIR)
           @echo Creating build directory

   $(OUT_DIR):
       mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR)

   install: $(TARGET)
       install $(TARGET) $(PREFIX)
   ```
3. hello.bb recipe

   ```
   # Recipe created by recipetool
   # This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
   # (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

   # Unable to find any files that looked like license statements. Check the accompanying
   # documentation and source headers and set LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM accordingly.
   #
   # NOTE: LICENSE is being set to "CLOSED" to allow you to at least start building - if
   # this is not accurate with respect to the licensing of the software being built (it
   # will not be in most cases) you must specify the correct value before using this
   # recipe for anything other than initial testing/development!
   LICENSE = "CLOSED"
   LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

   # No information for SRC_URI yet (only an external source tree was specified)
   SRC_URI = ""

   # NOTE: this is a Makefile-only piece of software, so we cannot generate much of the
   # recipe automatically - you will need to examine the Makefile yourself and ensure
   # that the appropriate arguments are passed in.

   do_configure () {
       # Specify any needed configure commands here
       :
   }

   do_compile () {
       # You will almost certainly need to add additional arguments
       oe_runmake
   }

   do_install () {
       # This is a guess; additional arguments may be required
       oe_runmake install
   }

   FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/*"
   ```

Comment: Does 'make install' in your project (or do_install in your recipe)  install the correct files? I think you'll have to share the Makefile and recipe if you want better help.

Comment: I have edited the question with additional details

Comment: Doesn't look like you set the ````FILES```` variable? If I recall correctly you need to specify this field to tell bitbake what files to add to the install package.

Comment: I added :
FILES_${PN} =  "${bindir}/*"

still same problem